# Change css property after stop animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, if-statement, slide

I want to change a text color after a animation is completed.

I try this :

http://jsfiddle.net/WvAaK/2/

But doesn't work ! :/

```
var menuState="closed";
$("#MENU").click(function() { 
if (menuState=="closed") {
$("#SOUSMENU").animate({height: "300px"}, 1000);
menuState="open";
} else if (menuState=="open"){
$("#SOUSMENU").animate({height: "0px"}, 1000);
menuState="closed";}});
$("#MENU").click(function() { 
if (menuState=="open") {
  $("h1").css('color','red');
} else if (menuState=="closed"){
$("h1").css('color','black');
  menuState="closed"; }
});
```

Thanks for your precious help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the callback of `.animate`

```
var menuState="closed"; 
$("#MENU").click(function() { 
    if (menuState=="closed") {
        $("#SOUSMENU").animate({height: "300px"}, 1000, function() {
            $("h1").css('color','red');    
        });
        menuState="open";
    } else if (menuState=="open"){
        $("#SOUSMENU").animate({height: "0px"}, 1000, function() {
            $("h1").css('color','black');
        });
        menuState="closed";
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WvAaK/3/

Comment: @user2657939 there is also little bit different fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WvAaK/4/